# Структуры, ошибка vector Out of range

Tags: c++

Задача такова

> Описать используя структуру, жителей(фамилия, город, улица, дом, квартира). Составьте программу, которая печатает фамилии двух любых жителей из списка, живущих 
>    в разных городах по одинаковому адресу.

После ввода всех данных,фамилии,города и т.д. выдает ошибку

> vector subcript out of range

Я понимаю что одна из переменных выходит за рамки вектора, но в чем именно я допустил ошибку?

```
   #include <iostream> 
    #include<Windows.h> 
    #include <sstream> 
    #include <string>
    #include <vector> 
    using namespace std;
    using namespace msclr::interop;
    struct peoples {
        string fam;
        string city;
        string street;
        int home;
        int kvart;

    };
    std::vector<peoples> list;

    int main() {
    int c;                              
    SetConsoleCP(1251);                 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    cout << "Введите количество человек : ";
    cin >> c;

    string fam;
    string city;
    string street;
    int home;
    int kvart;


    for (int i = 0; i != c; i++) {
        cout << "Введите фамилию " << i+1 << " человека : ";
        cin >> fam;
        cout << "Введите город " << i + 1 << " человека : ";
        cin >> city;
        cout << "Введите улицу " << i + 1 << " человека : ";
        cin >> street;
        cout << "Введите дом " << i + 1 << " человека : ";
        cin >> home;
        cout << "Введите квартиру " << i + 1 << " человека : ";
        cin >> kvart;

        list.push_back({fam, city,street,home,kvart });
        cout << "=============================" << endl;

    }

    int num = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (num = 0; num < 5; num++) {

        for (k = 5; k > num; k - 1) {

            if (list[num].city != list[k].city && list[num].home == list[k].home && list[num].street == list[k].street && list[num].kvart == list[k].kvart) {
                cout << " Найден одинаковый адрес с разными городами" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << "=============================" << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Что такое `5`? Откуда взялось это `5`? Что делает `k - 1` в этом цикле `for (k = 5; k > num; k - 1)`?

Comment: `for (num = 0; num < list.size(); num++) ` и `for (k = num; k < list.size(); k++) ` в любом случае второй for делает что то странное.

Comment: Точно, проблема была в цикле, просто я нашел этот цикл в одной из тем stackoverflow, и решил использовать в своей программе.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если вы используете C++, то разумно использовать инструменты этого языка.

В вашем случае, гораздо проще будет использовать `find_if`:

```
for (num = 0; num < list.size(); num++)
{

   auto a = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
             [=](const peoples & p) -> bool {
               return ("ваш набор проверок: p.city == list[num].city итд");
             });
   if (a != list.end())
      std::cout << "found!";

}
```

Подробнее про `find_*` https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

При таком решении, разумно добавить поле `id` в `struct peoples`, для быстрой идентификации обьекта. И тогда получиться такой код:

```
 ...
  [=](const peoples & p) -> bool {
         if (p.id == list[num].id) return false;
           return ("ваш набор проверок: p.city == list[num].city итд");
         });
 ...
```

Если вводить дополнительное поле нет возможности из каких-то соображений, можно попробывать использовать `memcmp`:

```
 ...
  [=](const peoples & p) -> bool {
         if (memcmp(&p,&list[num],sizeof(p)) == 0) return false;
           return ("ваш набор проверок: p.city == list[num].city итд");
         });
 ...
```

Comment: не очень то разумная идея использовать `memcmp` в `c++` для классов. Не лучше уж перегрузить `bool operator==`?

Comment: хоть и не прочитал, но ответ  не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу

Comment: Мне помог ваш комментарий сверху, я изменил на `for (num = 0; num < list.size(); num++) `и `for (k = num; k < list.size(); k++) ` и всё заработало, также попробовал ваш вариант, он тоже работает, спасибо!

Comment: Предпочтительней использовать C++ алгоритмы в C++ программе, хотя безусловно оба варианта рабочие.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, описать как перегрузить оператор мне кажется будет довольно сложно для ТС, да и для этой задачи тоже.

Comment: @NewView что сдесь сложного? Обычный метод, а с помощью `std::tie` он весь займет всего 3 строчки. Ну а насчет "оба варианта рабочие" - это в корне НЕ ВЕРНО!!! И я даже опущу момент с наследованием и виртуальной таблицей функций: просто ответте мне на токой вопрос - `std::string a{"hello"}; std::string b{"hello"}; memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a));` - сдесь мы получим `true` или `false`? А ведь именно это вы и называете 'рабочим вариантом'

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, `sizeof(std::string));` - это дичь наверное :) там должно быть `a.length()` и `a.data()`, а про 'оба рабочих' я имел в виду вариант с циклами `for` и вариант с `find_if`, с memcmp выглядит не очень красиво с точки зрения C++ синтаксиса, но тоже работает. Не все типы конечно можно так проверять, но структуры можно.

Comment: @NewView понятное дело - дичь, но именно это у вас и происходит. В структуре `peoples` ведь аж 3 строки! Как по вашему они сравниваются? Правильный ответ - то что вы сами и назвали дичью!

Comment: я проверил его вариант с `find_if`, его я и назвал рабочим

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, сравниваются они побайтно, независимо от количества строк внутри и прочих погодных условий. Вас смущает `sizeof(p)` ? я вот этого не понимаю.. можно написать полностью тип `sizeof(struct peoples)`, или вы что то иное имеете в виду?

Comment: @NewView где я писал, что меня смущает именно это? Я, по-моему, писал о том, что нельзя сравнивать сложные структуры с помощью `memcmp`, и написал почему (пример со стрингом + таблица виртуальных функций в случае наследования). Это сравнение будет выдавать `true` только в том случае, если справа и слева одна и та же структура! Тобишь вариант с `memcmp`, В ДАННОМ СЛУЧАЕ, будет выдавать тотже результат что и `&a == &b` - только это будет гораздо быстрее (но все так же неправильно, ну или правильно, в случае если вам нужно проверить, если это не один и тот же объект).

Comment: @propane67 проверили? ну так скажите мне, что выдаст этот вариант при сравнении двух разных структур с идентичными данными?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, так правильно! Наша задача в этом примере выявить одинаковую!! структуру из одного и того-же вектора, чтобы не проверять ее саму с собой и не выдавать на нее предупреждение что данные совпадают! :) В этом смысл этой проверки в данной задаче. Посмотрите еще раз на код, она стоит первой проверкой до проверки самих данных.

Comment: @NewView так если ваша задача выявить одну и ту же, опять таки, зачем вам `memcmp`? Если она одна и та же, то оба значения будут иметь тот же адрес. И что будет работать быстрее: сравнить 8 байт или 104 (минимум, в зависимости от оптимизации может быть больше)? И я даже не говорю про иллюзию "правильной" работы вашего сравнения

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, вопрос вкуса, я предложил это в качестве варианта, как потенциально возможного, не более.. но мне по чему то кажется что в собранном коде `a == b` в случае C++ структур компилятором будет преобразовано в подобие memcp, но это предположение.

Comment: @NewView вы меня просто поражаете! Возьмите любую нормальную книгу по `c++` и прочитайте от корки до корки (в вашем случае достаточно и Прата), чтобы таких глупых мыслей у вас не возникало (и не советовать это еще и другим)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94403/discussion-between-newview-and-andrej-levkovitch).

Answer (score 2):

Следующим циклом:

```
for (num = 0; num < 5; num++) {

        for (k = 5;   k - 1) {..}
```

вы задаете следующую команду:

```
num = 0;  
k = 5; // откуда это число, непонятно
if ( num < 5  &&  k > num; ) 
//если чуть чуть подумаете, то это условие верно всегда
//так что вы получаете бесконечный цикл. И дальше:
if (list[num].city != list[k].city // и т.д
/*stop! вы до этого  вектор заполняли некоторым количеством элементов
это количество вы ввели в переменную `c`.  Что вы ввели, никому неизвестно, поэтому уже может быть выход за пределы. */
//дальше:
num++;
k - 1;
```

так как вы получили бесконечный цикл, то значение `num`  увеличивается бесконечно, а это уже не только очевидный выход  за пределы... А   `k - 1`  это есть некое значение, записанное в другое(временное) переменное, а значение `k`  вообше не меняется. Так что у вас не одна ошибка, а целая куча очевидных логических ошибок, и вам стоит понимать что пишете, а не просто взять и написать(лишбы было)